# Does Empower spell increase the damage dealt by a Mage's Sword?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, metamagic

A [*mage's sword*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-s-sword/) brings into being a sword that deals 4d6+3 force damage per round to a target. Can I use the metamagic Empower Spell on this spell to make the sword deal 50% extra damage on each hit?

I assume yes, because it's a variable numeric effect in the spell description, but also I guess the attacks of a creature created by *summon monster* wouldn't be empowered that way so I am a little confused.

Can a mage's sword be empowered to deal extra damage?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, you can Empower *mage's sword*

There's nothing in the description of either the Empower Spell feat or the *mage's sword* spell that precludes them working together. *Mage's sword* is a spell with a variable numeric effect - the damage it deals - and so if it is empowered it increases that damage by 50%.

If you were to empower a *summon monster* spell, you're correct that the damage that the summoned creatures deal is not increased by 50%, as the damage dealt by a summoned monster is not a variable property of the spell itself. You would, however, summon 50% more monsters than usual, if you used one of the forms of the spell that summons a randomly determined number of creatures.

Comment: Well I largely agree with the answer, you have to prove why SM does not get the same treatment. What is different between the two, why would one get empowered and not the other?

Comment: @Fering the monster's attacks are not a numeric effect of the spell - the spell's Effect is that it summons monsters under your command.  The damage they do with claws or bites or fire blasts or whatever is not in the text of the spell, which may seem like a fine distinction but it's one the game makes reliably.  If you cast Shout at a mountain and cause an avalanche, the avalanche's damage is not Empowered either.

Comment: @user2754 and mages sword summons a sword that deals x damage. So why is the damage for the sword different than the summon?

Comment: The fact that you've made a sword (not summoned it; Mordenkainen's sword is an evocation effect) is different from the fact that you cast a spell and 1d4 hellhounds are here now. You cast summon monster and hellhounds that already existed are brought to you for a brief period; your spellcasting talent (the grade of summon monster you cast, the caster level) defines how many (1, 1d3, 1d4+1) and how long they stay here. Meanwhile, with Mordenkainen's sword, your spellcasting talent (caster level) determines the quality of the blade you create—how effective it can be (attack bonus)—and duration.